# compilation amiitool impossible (MinGW)

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw

I wish compiled amiitool:

https://github.com/socram8888/amiitool

But I can not do it, I read on the author's deposit that people also had problems:
https://github.com/socram8888/amiitool/issues/9

So I allowed myself to posted here.

My configuration: Windows 10, MinGW(add my path system) version:GCC-6.3.0-1 6.3.0, Cmder

My main goal is to know how to compile amiitool with my current configuration.
For information when I try to compile a little hello world everything works fine.

Thanks to all for your help.

I resume everything from scratch:

In my case what works is this version of mingw32:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64-dgn/?source=typ_redirect

so I propose suddenly, I can turn my post into a little tutorial to help those like me, who starts!
Thanks to iBug for his invaluable help,

1) clone repository amiitool:

```
git clone https://github.com/socram8888/amiitool.git
```

--> at this stage the folder mbedtls is empty

2) clone repository mbedtls:

```
git clone "https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls"
```

3) update module:

```
git submodule
```

--> at this stage the folder mbedtls is ok

3) like you for this command I used cmd and not Cmder

```
set CC=gcc
```

4) editing the Makefile (root) file

```
PWD ?= "`pwd`" remplace for : PWD ?= .

gitversion.h:
    echo #define GIT_COMMIT_ID 0x12345678 > $(PWD)/gitversion.h
    echo #define GIT_COMMIT_COUNT 888 >> $(PWD)/gitversion.h
```

5)  compilation:

```
mingw32-make PWD=%CD%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all**, be prepared that you'll keep running into a series of problems because the program is designed for Unix systems, so there's a lot to do before you can compile it on Windows.

I use MinGW ([latest download from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)) + Windows Command Prompt (with MinGW added to `%PATH%`). To start, I right-clicked in the `amiitools` directory and selected "Open Command Prompt here".

Before compiling, make sure you got the submodule right by running the following command in the working directory

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then, as MinGW does not have `cc.exe` bundled (as opposed to Unix systems), you should use `gcc.exe`. Either modify the Makefile, or run `set CC=gcc` (I use Windows Command Prompt `cmd.exe`), or specify the compiler when running `make` (as shown below).

Then you need to do some changes to Makefile. Replace all backticked commands with actual strings or random stuff, like these (the number before each line is the line number):

```
 3 PWD ?= .
52     echo #define GIT_COMMIT_ID 0x12345678 > $(PWD)/gitversion.h
53     echo #define GIT_COMMIT_COUNT 888 >> $(PWD)/gitversion.h
```

- The modification to line 3 doesn't seem necessary, see below.

Note that on line 52 and line 53, you need to remove the double quotes as `echo` in CMD is different from `echo` in Unix.

You're done. Now run `make` to get everything compiled. You should not run into troubles anymore:

```
mingw32-make CC=gcc PWD=%CD%
```

Good luck.

[image]

---

As requested, here's my full log including version info of the tools I use:

```
D:\Desktop\amiitool>notepad Makefile

D:\Desktop\amiitool>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


D:\Desktop\amiitool>mingw32-make --version
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

D:\Desktop\amiitool>mingw32-make CC=gcc PWD=%CD%
echo #define GIT_COMMIT_ID 0x12345678 > D:\Desktop\amiitool/gitversion.h
echo #define GIT_COMMIT_COUNT 666 >> D:\Desktop\amiitool/gitversion.h
"mingw32-make" lib -C D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls CFLAGS="-DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE='\"D:\Desktop\amiitool/configs/mbedtls.h\"' -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char"
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Desktop/amiitool/mbedtls'
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/Desktop/amiitool/mbedtls/library'
"  CC    aes.c"
"  CC    aesni.c"
"  CC    arc4.c"
"  CC    asn1parse.c"
"  CC    asn1write.c"
"  CC    base64.c"
"  CC    bignum.c"
"  CC    blowfish.c"
"  CC    camellia.c"
"  CC    ccm.c"
"  CC    cipher.c"
"  CC    cipher_wrap.c"
"  CC    cmac.c"
"  CC    ctr_drbg.c"
"  CC    des.c"
"  CC    dhm.c"
"  CC    ecdh.c"
"  CC    ecdsa.c"
"  CC    ecjpake.c"
"  CC    ecp.c"
"  CC    ecp_curves.c"
"  CC    entropy.c"
"  CC    entropy_poll.c"
"  CC    error.c"
"  CC    gcm.c"
"  CC    havege.c"
"  CC    hmac_drbg.c"
"  CC    md.c"
"  CC    md2.c"
"  CC    md4.c"
"  CC    md5.c"
"  CC    md_wrap.c"
"  CC    memory_buffer_alloc.c"
"  CC    oid.c"
"  CC    padlock.c"
"  CC    pem.c"
"  CC    pk.c"
"  CC    pk_wrap.c"
"  CC    pkcs12.c"
"  CC    pkcs5.c"
"  CC    pkparse.c"
"  CC    pkwrite.c"
"  CC    platform.c"
"  CC    ripemd160.c"
"  CC    rsa.c"
"  CC    sha1.c"
"  CC    sha256.c"
"  CC    sha512.c"
"  CC    threading.c"
"  CC    timing.c"
"  CC    version.c"
"  CC    version_features.c"
"  CC    xtea.c"
"  AR    libmbedcrypto.a"
"  RL    libmbedcrypto.a"
"  CC    certs.c"
"  CC    pkcs11.c"
"  CC    x509.c"
"  CC    x509_create.c"
"  CC    x509_crl.c"
"  CC    x509_crt.c"
"  CC    x509_csr.c"
"  CC    x509write_crt.c"
"  CC    x509write_csr.c"
"  AR    libmbedx509.a"
"  RL    libmbedx509.a"
"  CC    debug.c"
"  CC    net_sockets.c"
"  CC    ssl_cache.c"
"  CC    ssl_ciphersuites.c"
"  CC    ssl_cli.c"
"  CC    ssl_cookie.c"
"  CC    ssl_srv.c"
"  CC    ssl_ticket.c"
"  CC    ssl_tls.c"
"  AR    libmbedtls.a"
"  RL    libmbedtls.a"
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/Desktop/amiitool/mbedtls/library'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Desktop/amiitool/mbedtls'
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c amiitool.c -o amiitool.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c keygen.c -o keygen.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c drbg.c -o drbg.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c util.c -o util.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c version.c -o version.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char -c amiibo.c -o amiibo.o
gcc -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/include -I D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/include -Wall -pedantic -O2 -fsigned-char keygen.o drbg.o util.o version.o amiibo.o amiitool.o -o amiitool -L D:\Desktop\amiitool/mbedtls/library -l mbedcrypto

D:\Desktop\amiitool>
```

Comment: @yave I use the newest MinGW from SourceForge. If you get it from SF you should have a graphical installer. Just keep clicking Next to get the default and latest.

Comment: @yave Did you actually compile amiitool? Then let's clean up the comments here. I'll merge the information into my answer later.

Comment: @yave Comments are meant for critique or requesting clarification, etc. Cleanup of comments are often accompanied with editing to the question or answer, to merge useful information into the body of the post. Feel free to edit your question to add whatever you think that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & easy build instructions for Windows using MSYS2:

- Install MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org/
- Update MSYS2

  - `pacman -Syu`
  - Restart
  - `pacman -Su`
- Install required packages:

  - `pacman -S base-devel gcc git`
- Clone amiitool repository:

  - `git clone https://github.com/socram8888/amiitool.git --recursive`
- Build amiitool:

  - `cd amiitool`
  - `make`